# Will wrapping components inside of <CSSTransition /> have any side effects?

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions

```
  <CSSTransition
      in={is_ready}
      nodeRef={comp_ref}
      timeout={speed}
      unmountOnExit
      classNames={classNames}
    >
      <OriginalComponent ref={comp_ref}>{children}</OriginalComponent>
  </CSSTransition>
```

Of course, the only reason why I am doing this is to use transition animation. But everything else should be completely as before.

Can this be trusted? What if for example, if `OriginalComponent` is related to the parent in some way, eg flex-box:

before:

```
  <div className="some-parent-class">
      <OriginalComponent ref={comp_ref}>{children}</OriginalComponent>
  </div>
```

now:

```
<div className="some-parent-class">
  <CSSTransition
      in={is_ready}
      nodeRef={comp_ref}
      timeout={speed}
      unmountOnExit
      classNames={classNames}
    >
      <OriginalComponent ref={comp_ref}>{children}</OriginalComponent>
  </CSSTransition>
</div>
```

As you can see now, the structure has be altered